# How to control the value of a Cell in Excel using an IF Then Statement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am currently working on an excel application where I have a macro, operated by a button click, which resets the numerical values within certain cells in a table.

Within this table there are 3 columns; "Quantity Fitted (n)", "Quantity Required (m)" and "Lock Configuration".

What I need to happen, is when the button is clicked, the numerical values for each line within the "Quantity Fitted (n)" column are reset to match the values displayed within the "Quantity Required (m)" column of the same line.

However, if the cell value within the "Lock Configuration" column of that row is set to "locked", I want the "Quantity Fitted (n)" value to remain unchanged after the button click.

I hope this makes sense! Here's my current attempt to code this:

```
Public Sub Reset_Quantity_Fitted()
'Macro to make quantity fitted equal to quantity required

    Dim DatRange2 As String

    quantity_required = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).ListObjects("Table_" & ActiveSheet.Name).ListColumns("Quantity Required (m)").DataBodyRange

    Set DatRange = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).ListObjects("Table_" & ActiveSheet.Name).ListColumns("Quantity Fitted (n)").DataBodyRange
    DatRange2 = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).ListObjects("Table_" & ActiveSheet.Name).ListColumns("Lock Configuration").DataBodyRange

    If DatRange2 = "Locked" Then
        DatRange = DatRange
    Else
        DatRange = quantity_required
    End If

End Sub
```

I don't think I'm too far away, but when running this code I get the following error:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT! Following the advice from BigBen below, I've attempted the following code, but still receive the same mismatch error. Can anybody help?

```
Public Sub Reset_Quantity_Fitted()
'Macro to make quantity fitted equal to quantity required

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rng = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).ListObjects("Table_" & ActiveSheet.Name).ListColumns("Quantity Fitted (n)").DataBodyRange

For Each cell In rng.Cells

    If rng.Offset(, 5) = "Locked" Then
        cell = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).ListObjects("Table_" & ActiveSheet.Name).ListColumns("Quantity Fitted (n)").DataBodyRange
    Else
        cell = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).ListObjects("Table_" & ActiveSheet.Name).ListColumns("Quantity Required (m)").DataBodyRange
    End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Use a loop perhaps.

Comment: @BigBen apologies for asking perhaps a basic question, but how exactly would a loop be used here?

Comment: `Dim rng as Range`, `For Each rng in DatRange`...

Comment: @BigBen thank you, I'm not sure how exactly to implement this but will look into it now. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @BigBen I've made an edit above with an attempt of a loop, but I'm still getting the same error. Are you able to offer any guidance?

Comment: My comment has `Dim rng as Range`.... I don't see that you tried that yet? You can use `Offset` too.

Comment: @BigBen I've just completed a second edit above using the `Dim rng as Range` approach but still no luck. Am I along the right lines do you think?

Comment: `If rng.Offset(,2).Value = "Locked" Then`... `

Comment: @BigBen I've tidied up my edits above, with the most recent reflecting your suggestion. Thank you for all the help so far, from what I can tell this should work, but it's still throwing up the same mismatch error?

Comment: Keep working with `rng`.... don't use `DatRange` or `quantity_required`.

Comment: @BigBen I'm now working exclusively with `rng` (please see above). I don't understand why I'm still seeing this mismatch error? How can I be assigning a value between two different variable types?

Comment: In your current version of the loop, you should be working with `cell`, which represents an *individual* cell.

Comment: @BigBen I tried that first, and have now gone back to trying it again (please see above). Still no luck and still the same mismatch error. It's frustrating lol I'm attempting something that should be relatively simple and I'm not sure what VBA doesn't like about my code.